# Error when running migrate command Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to deploy my first web project on a server. I am getting this error when running migrate and makemigrations:

```
ProgrammingError (1146, "Table '<user>$<dbname>.<table_name>'' doesn't exist")
```

Everywhere it says that you should run `manage.py syncdb` but this is obsolete , also when running `manage.py --run-syncdb` the same error is given.

**models**

```
class Book(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

snipppets from **settings**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<your_username>$<your_database_name>',
        'USER': '<your_username>',
        'PASSWORD': '<your_mysql_password>',
        'HOST': '<your_mysql_hostname>',
    }
} #Everything is replaced with the correct credentials

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main_app',
    'accounts',
]
```

The DB is empty on the server. On my PC (when I developed it locally) it worked, it created the table for me when it didn't exist in the DB.

I am using Django 1.11 and Mysql 5.6.27.

I tried other answers but did not help me.
Can you please suggests what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Please paste in the traceback for the error, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use migrations mechanism: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/

```
./manage.py makemigrations # this creates migrations files
./manage.py migrate # this applies migrations
```

Comment: but for first time user has to run syncdb once, right?? @bluszcz

Comment: As far I am aware, no.

Comment: is it obsolete in `django 1.11`, upto `1.7` its needed

Comment: He is using Django 1.11 as he wrote, so syncdb is out of sync ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use syncdb.
for the first time you creating your Django project in order to creating pre-installed apps (such as admin interface) database in django you need to use :
`python manage.py migrate` 

it creates all necessary database tables and relations.
but every time you make changes to your app like creating new columns in your models, you can use:
`python manage.py makemigrations [your app name]`

the result will be something like below :

`(env35) someone@shell:~/bookstore$ python manage.py makemigrations books
Migrations for 'books':
  0005_publisher_family.py:
    - Add field family to publisher`


and finally you run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

> to Synchronizes the database state with the current set of models and
>   migrations.